# Correct 2 to 1 Multiplexer Truth Table

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, logic-gates

What is the correct way to write a 2 to 1 multiplexer truth table?

In a couple of tutorials I've come across ([1](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html),[2](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-9/multiplexers/)), the table is presented as follows:

[image: typical 2 to 1 mux]

However, the same tutorials show the 4 to 1 multiplexor truth table as follows:

[image: typical 4 to 1 mux]

If this is the case, then why is the 2 to 1 truth table **not** the following?

[image: expected 2 to 1 mux]

I've also come across other tutorials([3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer),[4](http://www.asic-world.com/digital/combo4.html#Multiplexer),[5](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/mux.html)) that show the 2 to 1 multiplexer as I would expect it to be (second case), and to me it seems the most consistent approach considering that all the larger multiplexers (n to 1) shown in the tutorials follow this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A multiplexer is a collection of gates where none are arranged to retain an internal state.  A truth table of all possible input combinations can be used to  describe such a device.  A 2:1 multiplexer has 3 inputs.  Therefore a complete truth table has 2^3 or 8 entries.  The truth tables in the question only has 4 entries and therefor falls short of describing a 2:1 multiplexer.

Interestingly, most of the links in the question have 2:1 multiplexer truth tables that have 8 entries.

The switch diagrams are generally used in block diagrams where a 2:1 multiplexer is part of a larger circuit.  However, the more common symbol used look like this:

[image]

As for which input is passed through to the multiplexor's output based on the value of the selection line... If pressed I would say the 3rd table is the expected behavior.  I would expect a selection value of zero to pass the 1st input and a selection value of one to pass the 2nd and so on.  That is not to say the 1st table is wrong.  It too represents a multiplexer.  In fact, if all the selection lines were inverted (in this case there is only 1) this would be the expected behavior.

Comment: The tables I shared above are **condensed**. I excluded the other values because they are 'don't care' values. The expanded truth tables still follow the same pattern so this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I know what a multiplexer is and how it works. I am curious about the discrepancy between the 2:1 truth table and all the other n:1 multiplexers.

Comment: I see what you mean.  However, the zero outputs you have omitted are important. In a real circuit, you could implement your truth table by simply connecting the output to the positive rail of the supply.

Comment: Oh!  I see your confusion! Still, you shouldn't "condense" truth tables like that...  If pressed, I would say the logic appears backwards in the 1st truth table.  A "selector" value of zero implies the mux would pass the 1st input "d0".  A "selector" value of one... the 2nd input "d1" and so on.  In the 1st table it is as if the "selector" pin was inverted.  You might check to see it that was the original intent of that particular mux's design.

Comment: Yah, that's what I'm asking. So the tutorials linked are all misleading in the sense that they do not specify that the selector pin is inverted? If you look at the logic diagrams they all show the selector pin as not inverted. For example the diagram and truth table in [this tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html). From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer#Digital_demultiplexers), "a logic value of 0 would connect d0 to the output while a logic value of 1 would connect d1". Which implies that the second 2:1 mux table is the correct one.

Comment: I would say we're splitting hairs regarding the 2:1 mux selector. I can see you understand the concept well enough to know how a mux works or, more importantly, how to use it. I'm not a fan of how electronics-tutorials.ws abbreviates the 4:1 mux truth table.  You can take a quick census of how most of the web treats muxes by doing an IMAGE search on "4:1 multiplexer table". Some list all 8 combinations, some list 4 combinations but use a letter indicating which input is being used as the output & I see only a few doing it the way electronics-tutorials.ws does with only 1s for the output.